# Autolayout constraint issue for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

[When I switch orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiKx7.png)[image: Constrain Issue]

Hi, I am trying to get my table to be constrained with all selected in the left side of the picture. It is giving me errors which you can see on the right. Can anyone help me fix those errors? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping if you did!

Comment: Can you show me your View hierarchy? And Please mention what constraints you give to every component. Specify individually.

Comment: Define the constraints for the slider first. How do you expect the table to position itself if you don't define constraints for the slider?

Comment: I tried, same mistake. Thanks for helping anyways!

Answer (score -2):

Click on "Resolve Auto Layout issues"  and select "reset to suggested constraint". It'll be helpful for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but after I try that I switch orientations and it's messed up, this was also happening before. I added a picture of what it looks like after orientation is switched. Thanks!

Comment: Adding constraints from suggestion is not a good practice because when you add constraints from suggestion `x-code` adds constraints according to it. It can remove your error by it does not satisfy your **UI design format**. And many times it hard to identify which constraints `x-code` added in our components.